# Can I put a break in an if statement that is in a for loop in java?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, break

So I'm trying to put a break in an if statement, which in turn is in a "for" loop.

```html
for( int i = 0; i < 52; i++ )
{
  int x = 1;
  if( x == 1 )
      break;
}
```

Does this break the for loop?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Yes, otherwise the loop would only step once and be senseless.

Comment: Yes it will, but your code doesn't make sense. Please post correct code and provide context for it.

Comment: Yes it would but what is that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you want the `break` directly in the `for` block? (Also worth noting that the block is, in a sense, optional - it can be any statement not just a block statement.)

Comment: To everyone saying the code doesn't make sense, I am aware of that. I was just providing an example.

Comment: I think your `x` is from outside the for loop and you would want to break if(i==x).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, we put the break statement inside the for loop when we have specific condition and if that condition is satisfied then we don't want to run the loop to check further steps.

**Regarding your question**: Yes this will break the for loop,
But as according to your code snippet, you are setting x = 1, so only one time the for loop will be executed and after checking the if(x ==1 ) condition it will break.

Answer (score 0):

This will break from the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can put break inside a loop. In your case you have assigned 1 to x and just after that checking if(x==1) mean it will be true and break will get executed and it will take you out of the loop